# How to Add New TestCases to an existing Rally Folder

Tags: rally

I tried the below code to create test cases under existing folder. I'm able to create the testcase but dont see it under the associated folder.

```
    QueryRequest testFolderRequest = new QueryRequest("TestFolder");
    testFolderRequest .setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID", "Name"));

    QueryResponse testFolderQueryResponse = restApi.query(testsetRequest);
    // JsonObject testSetJsonObject =
    // testSetQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
    String testFolderReference = testFolderQueryResponse.getResults().get(0)
            .getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").toString();
    // System.out.println("TestFolder object: "+testSetRef);

    JsonObject newTestCase = new JsonObject();
    newTestCase.addProperty("Name", "Newly added testcase in a folder");
    newTestCase.addProperty("Test Folder", testFolderReference);
    CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("testcase", newTestCase);
    CreateResponse response = restApi.create(createRequest);
    System.out.println(response.toString());
    JsonObject json = response.getObject();
    System.out.println(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Attributes in webservices API shouldn't have spaces. So:

`newTestCase.addProperty("TestFolder", testFolderReference);`

Should work.